# Why doesn't "parsetcl" produce output?

Tags: tcl, tclsh

I want to read `myfile.tcl` and traverse its structure (to enumerate procs and variables, stuff like that).

I am aware of the built-in `interp` command but it doesn't look like that will let me traverse the structure of what it parses, just evaluate it.

I tried https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/parsetcl but

a) It fails with `can't find package tcl 8.4`, I tried `package require tcl 8` and `package require tcl 8.5` but that didn't work either so I just commented it out

b) after that it still doesn't work, the below test script just hangs without producing output

```
source "lib/parsetcl.tcl"

proc _load {file_name} {
    set fp [open $file_name r]
    set file_data [read $fp]
    close $fp
    return $file_data
}

parsetcl::simple_parse_script [info body _load]
```

I also tried `parsetcl::format_tree [parsetcl::simple_parse_script [info body _load]] { } {   }`, same problem.

I'm executing these with `tclsh`, on Ubunut `apt` thinks I have packages `tcl tcl8.5 tcl8.6` installed.

Why isn't this working?

Comment: `package require Tcl version-number`. Note the upper case T.

Comment: I changed `tcl` to `Tcl` and now the `require` works, but the snippet still hangs with no output

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with the parse representation of a Tcl script? Why am I asking, because depending on what you want to do, `parsetcl` (above) or anything else won't help because the Tcl syntax is not very specific, for example: You won't get an authoritative list of variables (e.g., thinking of `set $varName 1` will be reported as a command substitution on top of a variable substitution, but you won't get any actual variable name ... because it is not known).

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing why `parsetcl` doesn't work or how to fix it, I have found that using `nagelfar` with a plugin for `statementWords` is a better solution to my main problem.

I will not accept this, my own, answer in case someone would like to post a fix for `parsetcl`.